# Adjetivos con dos sentidos en preguntas

Tags: adjetivos

¿Qué sentido tienen adjetivos como verde, rico o listo en preguntas sin verbo?

He visto '¿Listo?' en el sentido de 'Ready?' y no de 'Smart?' ¿Son siempre los sentidos 'estar'?

Comment: ¿Debo siempre comprenderlos con un verbo oculto alguno?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Voy a responder en español, tratando de no ser muy complicado. Si no comprendes algo sólo tienes que decirlo. Puedo traducirlo al inglés.

El sentido depende del contexto. No debes necesariamente pensar qué verbo está "oculto", sino **qué es más probable que el hablante quiera decir**. Y si no entiendes qué quiere decir, puedes preguntar.

Por ejemplo: Ana está terminando de responder un e-mail. Boris está esperando que Ana termine, porque van a salir juntos. Ana deja de escribir. Boris pregunta entonces: «¿Listo?». Lo que Boris quiere decir es «¿Ya está listo tu e-mail?», «¿Está listo lo que estabas haciendo?» («listo» puede significar «terminado»). También podría preguntar en femenino: «¿Lista?». En ese caso su pregunta se refiere a Ana y significa: «¿Ya estás lista para salir?».

Otro ejemplo: Boris le dice a Ana que conoció a Carlos, un amigo de Ana. Carlos no es muy inteligente, pero Boris dice: «Carlos me pareció un tipo listo.» Ana no puede creerlo y pregunta: «¿Listo?» En este caso la pregunta significa: «¿Escuché bien? ¿En serio crees que Carlos es listo?».

Podría darte muchos más ejemplos, pero lo importante es esto: **siempre hay un contexto** en la realidad, cuando hablas un idioma con alguien más o escuchas a alguien hablarlo. **Es casi imposible que te encuentres con una palabra suelta, sola, sin contexto alguno** que te permita adivinar qué significa. Por esa razón no existen reglas fijas que puedan decirte si «listo» significa *ready* o *smart*. El contexto siempre va a aclararte cuál es el significado.

Comment: Bien. Lo que pensaba antes de preguntarles era que estos adjetivos habrían tenido una forma básica y una modificada por el verbo 'estar' o 'ser'. Que 'listo' quiera decir 'intelligente' y que el verbo 'estar' le modifique, cambiandolo en 'preparado', por ejemplo. ¿Parece que la elección del verbo no es lo importante para vosotros y que sólo ven estos adjetivos como homónimas? Gracias para su respuesta muy aclaradora.

Comment: Como dices, se trata de homónimos, y el verbo no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: Pero en el caso de "listo," el 95 % de las veces, O MÁS, será *¿Está todo listo?*